# OpenLayers3 add map to bottom of a layer?

Tags: openlayers, basemap

According to [OpenLayers 3 documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#addLayer), the function

> addLayer(layer)
>
> ```
> Adds the given layer to the top of this map.
> ```

How can I add a layer to the **bottom** of a map?

P.S. I need this to add a background layer similar to a base layer in OpenLayers 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that I found a solution after some trial and error, i.e. simply use a `map`'s layers collection, and insert `layer` to the head position:

```
var layers = map.getLayers();
layers.insertAt(0,layer);
```

Comment: Do you have a working example of this? I seem to have come across a similar issue but can't get it to work