# Why don't I see my added layers when I choose another base map?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, basemap

I'm working on a small application with OpenLayers 3. In my file.js, I have added these four base maps as shown below:

```
var mapquest = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'}),
        visible: false,
        name: 'mapquest'
});
var bingmaps = new ol.layer.Tile({
    preload: Infinity,
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
      key: 'dY07ihXoIp15X3uz2p7u~XhaOOszGD1yRh0iA2siECg~ApUkGF8SU2HBMsmFOMX6wuknO-ehbjd919j8pD6Jg-fWqeJL97x3K3KtdApb7xTH',
      imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels',
    }),
    visible: true,
    name: 'bingmaps'
});
var esri = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: [
            new ol.Attribution({
                html: 'Tiles &copy; <a href="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' +
                'rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer">ArcGIS</a>'
            })
        ],
        url: 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
        'World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
    }),
    visible: false,
    name: 'esri'
});
var stamen = new ol.layer.Group({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.Stamen({ 
                layer: 'watercolor' 
            })
        }),
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.Stamen({ 
                layer: 'terrain-labels' 
            })
        })
    ],
    visible: false,
    name: 'stamen'
});
```

I've made visible: true for bingmaps as you can see. Then, in my file.html, I have made a list of these base maps so that the user can move from one to any other base map like he wants, as shown below:

```
<nav id="layers">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="layer" value="bingmaps" checked>Bing Maps</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="layer" value="mapquest">Mapquest OSM</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="layer" value="esri">ESRI Maps</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="layer" value="stamen">Stamen</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The Base map bingmaps is checked.
After that, I converted four shapefiles to GeoJSON files, as shown:

```
var vectorSourceCentre = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'mysql_geojson/CENTRES.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    projection: 'EPSG:4261'
});

var vectorLayerCentre = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSourceCentre,
    style: centreStyle
});
```

It's the same thing for the other shapefiles. I added them to the map:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
        new ol.control.ZoomSlider()
    ]),
    renderer: 'canvas',
    layers: [mapquest, bingmaps, esri, stamen, vectorLayerCentre, vectorLayerPba, vectorLayerHectometre, vectorLayerChambre],
    view: view
});
```

When I open the browser, I see my added layers on the base map bingmaps with no problem (bingmaps is what I've chosen as visible), but the problem is when I check any other base map such as ESRI maps or Stamen I don't see  my GeoJSON layers any more.

How could I fix this?

Comment: I think it must be some related to the order of your layers, can you add the code where you change the base layer ?

Comment: I think the problem is the ordering of your layers? The basemap should be added behind the vector layer. This could help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124760/openlayers3-add-map-to-bottom-of-a-layer

Comment: Should i have a code for changing basemaps? normally before i added the geojson layers, i was changing from a basemap to another one and it's working! Even after adding layers, changing basemaps is working but the added layers are shown only on bingmaps. Thks for replying.

Comment: i added this code :

Comment: var layers = map.getLayers();
 layers.insertAt(0,bingmaps);
 layers.insertAt(1,mapquest);
 layers.insertAt(2,esri);
 layers.insertAt(3,stamen);
 layers.insertAt(4,vectorLayerCentre);
 layers.insertAt(5,vectorLayerPba);
 layers.insertAt(6,vectorLayerHectometre);
 layers.insertAt(7,vectorLayerChambre);

Comment: but still the same problem. someone for help plz

Comment: @HichamZouarhi Mr Hicham, here is the function code for changing base layers: '$('#layers input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  var layer = $(this).val();

  map.getLayers().getArray().forEach(function(e) {
   var name = e.get('name');
   e.setVisible(name == layer);
  });
 });'. Something is wrong?

Comment: do this little check on your vector layer whenever you change base layer : `console.log(yourVectorLayer.getVisible());` please

Comment: @HichamZouarhi Mr Hicham, sould i do this check within changing function or where? Thks

Comment: @drissrais yes, I think the problem is that all layers are hiden except the one selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment in the question, you use this function to change the base layer :

```
$('#layers input[type=radio]').change(function() { 
    var layer = $(this).val(); 
    map.getLayers().getArray().forEach(function(e) {
        var name = e.get('name'); 
        e.setVisible(name == layer); 
    }); 
    //yourVectorLayer.setVisible(true);
 });
```

which does display the desired base layer but hides all the others
to display your vector layer you'll have to add the commented line to it

Comment: @drissrais you're welcome :) don't forget to accept it with the little check mark

Comment: Thank u Mr Hicham, but which check mark?

Comment: @drissrais at the left of the answer under the upvote and downvote arrows